# ObjectMapper Mapped to POJO Returns Null

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I have a simple Json in the following form:

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "productSku": "123",
      "productInventory": "24"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "productSku": "12350",
      "productInventory": "22"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "productSku": "12351",
      "productInventory": "19"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am grabbing this Json through a localhost URL and trying to map it to a POJO class in a different Spring Boot app that is running on a different port. The POJO class corresponding to the aforementioned Json is:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonRootName(value = "products")
public class Product {

    private Integer id;
    private String productSku;
    private String productInventory;

    //getters and setters omitted


}
```

The following is my controller that handled the mapping and binding:

```
@ResponseBody
    @GetMapping("index")
    public String getIndex() throws JsonParseException, 
       JsonMappingException, IOException {

        URL ApiUrlJson = new URL("http://localhost:1990/product");

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Product product = mapper.readValue(ApiUrlJson, Product.class);
        System.out.println(product.getProductInventory());

        return "Processed!";
    }
```

When I run the application and access index to get the value of a certain variable, the output is always null and I am not sure what I am missing?

Comment: The URL is product actually not products. When I access the URL without mapping it to the POJO class, I retrieve all the results just fine

Comment: `products` in your JSON file is an array, and the class `Product` is treating it like it is1 single product, not an array. I think that's the issue?

Comment: You mean create a new model containing a list of Product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to deserialize an array of JSONs. Also don't omit setters since the access for this variable is private. You can refer the code below. I have checked it and I am able to deserialize it properly.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Product {

  private Integer id;
  private String productSku;
  private String productInventory;

  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getProductSku() {
    return productSku;
  }

  public void setProductSku(String productSku) {
    this.productSku = productSku;
  }

  public String getProductInventory() {
    return productInventory;
  }

  public void setProductInventory(String productInventory) {
    this.productInventory = productInventory;
  }
}

class Products{

  private List<Product> products;

  public List<Product> getProducts() {
    return products;
  }

  public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
    this.products = products;
  }
}

public class Main{

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    String jsonString =
        "{\n"
            + "  \"products\": [\n"
            + "    {\n"
            + "      \"id\": 1,\n"
            + "      \"productSku\": \"123\",\n"
            + "      \"productInventory\": \"24\"\n"
            + "    },\n"
            + "    {\n"
            + "      \"id\": 2,\n"
            + "      \"productSku\": \"12350\",\n"
            + "      \"productInventory\": \"22\"\n"
            + "    },\n"
            + "    {\n"
            + "      \"id\": 3,\n"
            + "      \"productSku\": \"12351\",\n"
            + "      \"productInventory\": \"19\"\n"
            + "    }\n"
            + "  ]\n"
            + "}";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Products products = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Products.class);
    // To just access list of ids
    List<Product> productsList= products.getProducts();
    List<Integer> productIds = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Product product : productsList){
      productIds.add(product.getId());
    }
    System.out.println(productIds);
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the code to get a list of product ids. I don't know if it answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

You have a list of products in your JSON file. You are deserializing one object with 3 fields. None of these fields is under products, but you ignore missing fields.

Try deserializing to a new class containing a list of Product.
Remove @JsonRootName

Comment: You mean create a new model containing a list of Product?

Comment: Yes, precisely that. Also name this list field appropriately

Comment: You can process the list - get interesting one by index or use a predicate to find the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You have an object and inside that object is a list of objects. i.e.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonRootName(value = "products")
public class Products {
    private List<Product> products;

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(final List<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
}


public class Product{
.....
}

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Products product = objectMapper.readValue("json here....", Products.class);
System.out.println(product.getProducts().size());
```